# Running the timer on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have base class Timer and a couple of methods inside it. My idea is simple, I need a basic class to run the timer. A lot of various timers as the instances of base class. But I have no idea how should I pass method as a parameter inside the `.startTimer` and `.run`

```
function Timer(interval) {
        this.isTimerRuns = false;
        this.timerId = 0;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

Timer.prototype.run = function (foo) {
    if(this.isTimerRuns){
        foo();
        setTimeout(this.run(foo), this.interval);
    }
    else{
        this.stopTimer();
    }
};

Timer.prototype.startTimer = function (foo) {
    this.timerId = setTimeout(this.run(foo), this.interval);
    this.isTimerRuns = true;
};

Timer.prototype.stopTimer = function () {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
    this.isTimerRuns = false;
    this.timerId = 0;

};

Timer.prototype.ajaxCall = function (url, method, successFunc, errorFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        success: function (data) {
            var respond = JSON.parse(data);
            successFunc(respond);
        },
        error: function () {
            if(errorFunc != null){
                errorFunc();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

When I try to run my crap like this:

```
    var t = new Timer(10000);
    t.startTimer(t.ajaxCall("/123", "POST", test2, null));

function test2(resp) {
    console.log(resp + '!');
}
```

it runs only once and stops. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs once cause you execute the function instead of passing it as a parameter:

Do like this:

```
t.startTimer( function() { t.ajaxCall("/123", "POST", test2, null); });
```

Providing that the rest of your code does what you want, that should do the trick.

Comment: Yes. good spot.  As well as run method does not retain the timeout reference. So perhaps the whole class needs some rethinking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Timer(interval) {
        this.isTimerRuns = false;
        this.timerId = 0;
        this.interval = interval;
    }
Timer.prototype.startTimer = function (foo) {
 this.isTimerRuns = true;
    this.timerId = setInterval(foo, this.interval);
    
};

Timer.prototype.stopTimer = function () {
 clearInterval(this.timerId);
    this.isTimerRuns = false;
    this.timerId = 0;

};

Timer.prototype.ajaxCall = function (url, method, successFunc, errorFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        success: function (data) {
            var respond = JSON.parse(data);
            successFunc(respond);
        },
        error: function () {
            if(errorFunc != null){
                errorFunc();
            }
        }
    });
};

function test2(resp) {
    console.log(resp + '!');
}

  var t = new Timer(1000);
    t.startTimer(function(){t.ajaxCall("/123", "POST", test2, null)});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In javascript setInterval function available to call infinite execution with interval time like setTimeout, but setTimeout will execute once but not setInterval. we can control setInterval by using clearInteval(--inteval timer variable--).